# Can't get this query to work in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to return the officials name, the hotel they manage and the number of matches they have refereed from the below database (see relational diagram below).

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
select officials.name as Official,
hotels.name as Hotel, -- hotel the official manages
count (case when officials.name = matches.referee then 1 else null end) as Matchesrefereed
from officials
left join hotels
on  officials.staffid = hotels.manager
left join matches
on officials.staffid = matches.referee
where (case when hotels.name is null then '-' else hotels.name end); -- print '-' if does not manage hotel
```

I get a group function error for select, and the `case` statement at the end also doesn't work.

Relational diagram from reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your DBMS?

```
select 
   officials.name as Official,
   nvl(hotels.name, '-') as Hotel, -- hotel the official manages
   count (matches.referee) as Matchesrefereed
  from officials
  left join hotels on  officials.staffid = hotels.manager
  left join matches on officials.staffid = matches.referee
group by officials.name, nvl(hotels.name, '-')
```

Comment: It's almost correct except it sometimes returns a duplication record of an Official (and incorrectly assigns it to managing a hotel).

Comment: @Tangler can you provide some sample data? can a single official manage multiple hotels?

Comment: Sorry, it is in fact correct, the sample output was ordered differently and didn't notice that the duplicates should in fact be there. Thanks for the solution.